# JSON format for Generics in Play 2.x

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

my classes look like this

```
trait Value[T] {
  def get:T
}
```

I have implementations of this, for example

```
class StringValue(value : String) extends Value[String] {
  override def get : String = value
}

class NumberValue(value : Int) extends Value[Int] {
  override def get: Int = value
}
```

The problem is that I need to make jsonFormat for this types in order to save it to MongoDB.

I stucked for two days but still cannot figure out how to make it work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the provided [`.nullable`](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/master/play-json/shared/src/main/scala/JsConstraints.scala#L160) which returns `Reads` for `Option` (generic type), you need to first enforce that the type parameter of `Value` is itself provided the required instances of `Reads` and `Writes`.

So for a generic `Reads[Value[T]]` the minimal `def` would be as bellow.

```
def valueReads[T](implicit underlying: Reads[T]): Reads[Value[T]] = ???
```

Similarily, for `Writes[Value[T]]` (or `OWrites` if it needs to be restricted to JSON object, and thus BSON document), the minimal definition would be as following.

```
def valueWrites[T](implicit underlying: Writes[T]): Writes[Value[T]] = ???
// or
def valueOWrites[T](implicit underlying: Writes[T]): OWrites[Value[T]] = ??? // don't define both as implicit to avoid conflict
```

Then the implementation depends on the way you want to represent `Value[T]` as JSON.

Considering the following JSON representation:

```
{ "_value": ... }
```

... then the `Reads` would be something as bellow.

```
implicit def valueReads[T](implicit underlying: Reads[T]): Reads[Value[T]] =
  Reads[Value[T]] { json =>
    (json \ "_value").validate(underlying).map { t: T =>
      Value(t)
    }
  }
```

Similarily, the `OWrites[Value[T]]` would be as following.

```
implicit def valueWrites[T](implicit underlying: Writes[T]): OWrites[Value[T]] =
  OWrites[Value[T]] { value => Json.obj("_value" -> value) }
```

> Obviously, these implicits need to be in the implicit scope, either by being defined in the `Value` companion object, or by being explicitly imported if defined elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you, it seems more or less clear (at least it's good idea to look at Option example). How do you think what to do with case class Foo(attributes: Map[Attribute, Value[_]]) then?

Comment: You cannot, as `_` means the type parameter is unknown. You would need a `Foo[T]`

Comment: but I want this Map[Attribute, Value[_]] contain both types StringValue and NumberValue

Comment: you cannot, instance of typeclass are based on known type, if you remove types, your done (or you will do some unsafe/untyped code). You can have the type parameter known as a sealed family, defining as subtypes all the possible case (based on/allowing pattern matching)